# Change ios Frame Size(width e height) keeping position (x,y)

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios

How can i change Size of a Frame view and keep origin position? 
I tried with this code (but it didn't work):

```
myview.frame.size = CGSizeMake(23.0,50.0);
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here's how to do it with just one line of code:

```
myview.frame = CGRectMake(23, 50, myview.frame.size.width, myview.frame.size.height);
```

or

```
[myview setFrame:CGRectMake(23, 50, myview.frame.size.width, myview.frame.size.height)];
```

Comment: Ok so there isn't a method to set only size !

Comment: You can also go: `[myview setFrame:CGRectMake(23, 50, CGRectGetWidth(myview.frame), CGRectGetHeight(myview.frame))];`

Comment: @runmad Your answer is also the preferred way by Apple, see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html

Comment: shouldnt it be this instead? [myview setFrame:CGRectMake(myview.frame.origin.x, myview.frame.origin.y, newWidth, newHeight)];

Answer (score 35):

You need to set the whole frame at once. Try:

```
CGRect newFrame = myview.frame;
newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(23.0, 50.0);
myview.frame = newFrame;
```

Answer (score 3):

Not that I am aware of. Rather than change your view's frame property, you can change the bounds property so regardless of what you set for x and y, it wont affect your view position. Make sure that you use 0 for x and y.

```
self.myView.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0, newWidth, newHeight);
```