# Double tap UIwebview to full screen

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, webview, uiwebview

I want to double tap an UIwebview that has the size of (159,182) I want to expand it to full screen size (it covers the whole screen) I also want it, to be able to double tap the full webview again and then make it go to normal size (159, 182) is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Add a UITapGestureRecognizer to it. In viewDidLoad:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTap)];
doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
doubleTap.delegate = self;
[webView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
```

Don't forget to add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to your header file.

Remove the UITapGestureRecognizer in viewDidUnload.

Also add this method

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer    *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Then implement the code to resize your UIWebView in

```
- (void)doubleTap
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I still can't get it. its not working properly. Do you know any tutorials or websites that describes exactly this, a bit more specific?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: for the gestureRecognizer: http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567, for updating the frame of a view: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349551/change-ios-frame-sizewidth-e-height-keeping-position-x-y