# Dynamically changing size and frame position of UITextView

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

What I would like to do is to make a custom UITextView to allow dynamically changing size and positions of it like PicLab's text edit function.

[PicLab tools article](http://moblivious.com/reviews/piclab-hd-brings-multi-layered-text-editing-tool-iphone/)

[image]

In sum for my simple questions following
1, How to move a position of TextView at your disposal
2, How to change a size of TextView by finger slide
3, How to dynamically change size of fonts corresponding to size of TextView

That would be great if sharing me with useful links as well as codes.

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout?

Comment: Yes, I'm using AutoLayout!

Answer (score -1):

1. to move the *position* of a `UITextView` (actually of any UI element in iOS), you can modify its `frame` property. the `frame` property defines the *rectangle* that this elements takes on the screen, being defined with `x` and `y` positions ( *(0, 0)* is the top left corner of the screen).
2. you can also change the size of a `UITextView` by modifying the frame, this time instead of modifying `x` and `y`, you'll have to modify its `height` and `width`

an example of setting a `UITextField` with a `width` of *200* and `height` of *50* would look like in the top left corner of the screen looks like:

```
CGFloat x = 0.0;
CGFloat y = 0.0;
CGFloat width = 2000.0;
CGFloat height = 50.0;

textField.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)
```

3. the changing of the font size will have to be implemented dynamically by a custom function of yours, you can use the class method of `UIFont` `fontWithName:size` for this.

Comment: And in order to answer **how** to change a view's frame one could use gesture recognizers...

Comment: You cannot directly change the frame when using auto layout.

Comment: wasn't aware he was using AutoLayout. one option then is set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `YES` or otherwise instead of modifying the frame directly, setting appropriate constraints

Answer (score -2):

Frame cannot be set for coordinates and dimension directly, you have to assign a new object. A quick search found this, [Change ios Frame Size(width e height) keeping position (x,y)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349551/change-ios-frame-sizewidth-e-height-keeping-position-x-y).